# Network adapter device shows #2

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, device-manager

I tried [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/wifi-shows-as-wifi-2-and-unable-to-connect-to-any/f534a1e4-5bd0-46b2-97f6-2b468bc30705) but there are no ghost items.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

Open Device Manager, then:

1. Right-click on the device, then Uninstall device.
2. Scan for hardware changes. Windows will install the device without the #2.

Comment: Tried that. #2 still exists.